# How can I delay the publishing of a page or post?

Tags: draft, publish, scheduled-posts

Sometimes it would be nice to be able to set a draft to be published when I'm not in front of the keyboard. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since a picture is worth a thousand words:

1) Click "Edit" next to "Publish Immediately"

[image]

2) Change the date

[image]

3) Click "OK"

Comment: Others gave good answers, but the pictures did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: over 2000 words for such a simple answer!

Comment: Broken images are broken :( In future use the built ins tack exchange image uploader rather  than linking offsite to dropbox

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely. Above the publish button, where it says 'publish immediately', click edit and select the date/time you'd like it to publish. The buttons will say 'Schedule' after you save the new date.

Comment: Just be forewarned that this setting can have some *strange* behavior over daylight savings :-)  The post will save using the time settings of the day you wrote it, so when things update for daylight savings, it will shift by an hour either forwards or backwards.  Not a huge issue ... but it's confused both me and my readers at least twice.

Answer (score 3):

See: [**Writing Posts**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Posts) (emphasis added):

> **To schedule a post for publication on
>   a future time or date, click "Edit" in
>   the Publish area next to the words
>   "Publish immediately".** You can also
>   change the publish date to a date in
>   the past to back-date posts. Change
>   the settings to the desired time and
>   date. **You must also hit the "Publish"
>   button when you have completed the
>   post to publish at the desired time
>   and date.**

Answer (score 0):

Next to the post box, there is an 'edit' link next to the text 'Publish **Immediately**'.  Click that edit link, and you'll be able to schedule the post date/time.

Edit: oops. posted just after John.  Poor timing on my part1