# permalink %year% of pre-written posts to be published next year, in the mysterious future (*)

Tags: permalinks, scheduled-posts

I am pre-writing some posts that will be published next year.  My permalink structure is

```
/%year%/%postname%/
```

After setting the post title, the permalink says it will be

```
http://www.amazeaweek.net/2011/spiral-out/
```

which reflects the year I'm writing it.

But I'd like it to be

```
http://www.amazeaweek.net/2012/spiral-out/
```

because it will be published in 2012.

I tried setting the publish date *before* writing the title, but the permalink still says it will be 2011, even though the publish date is set to be next year.

**How can I make the permalink reflect the publish year instead of the current year?**

(*) I tried to make my question title include all the keywords I used trying to search for this answer.

After reading the note after this [answer regarding scheduling posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-can-i-time-the-publishing-of-a-page-or-post/25#25), I wonder if I simply have to wait until next year...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking [publish] once or twice, the permalink fixes itself automagically; I didn't see it before because I didn't want to save with the "wrong" permalink.